# Removing/Consuming Lambda expression events on javafx

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

So, I created an event with lambda expression in a canvas using `javafx` and I want it to be removed after used, here's the event:

```
can.setOnMouseExited(event->{
    gc.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    gc.strokeRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it as null at the end of the event :

```
can.setOnMouseExited(event->{
   gc.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
   gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
   gc.strokeRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
   can.setOnMouseExited(null);
});
```

**N.B.** This will call the `mouseExit` listener *just once*.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `can.setOnMouseExited(null)`.

Comment: Your answer was very usefull, I just didn't checked it as best because you didn't expanded and didn't use it in a code. Thank you for your help anyway, it worked!